# 3.9 breaks multisite

Tags: multisite

I just updated to 3.9 and all my sites are now the main (first) site on the network.

If I go to a subsite admin page the url will say that I am on my subsite but I am actually on the admin for the main site of the network. The admin bar will also show that the current site is the main network site, but the url says I should be on the subsite.

I created a new testing environment with multi site and the same thing happens. If I create a new subsite it will always direct me to the main site, but the urls will show the subsite address. (front end and backend/admin).

It seems like there is a major redirect issue happening.

Comment: Are you positive you've tried a vanilla install? i.e. no custom themes, plugins, MU plugins etc. Otherwise this is a massive bug and I'm surprised it creeped into release!

Comment: Yes I am positive...2 local installs and the same issue. Not sure what is causing it. Someone here is having the same issues even though the post is titled wrong. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/39-update-seems-to-have-erased-my-database-postscomments-erased?replies=15

Comment: I have a live testing multisite that I just updated and it seems to be working ok. Seems to be a random issue which may be how the bug escaped beta.

Comment: I have very similar problem, so it's not random issue. In my case the main website creates redirect loop.

Comment: I meant random in that it may work in some cases. It was not to diminish the severity of the issue. I have been doing a lot of testing with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Probably this issue: Multisite subdirectory install breaks if network path has uppercase letters. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27866

Comment: Must be...I just did another fresh install with all lower case, but now it goes into a redirect loop when trying to access the dashboard on the sub-site.

Comment: I just did another install and removed an underscore in the path name and everything seems to work ok. So from my testing...uppercase with an underscore creates a redirect issue and lowercase with an underscore causing a redirect loop.

Comment: We had a similar issue, but do not have uppercase names in the network path. Unfortunately, we were not able to find a solution and had to revert the code base.